# Авторизация на phpBB3 по ссылке без пароля

Tags: phpbb, php

Как произвести авторизацию пользователя на форуме phpBB3 по ссылке?
Ссылка не должна содержать пароля, для того чтобы совсем упростить задачу оставим в этой ссылке один только username (пользвоатели с основного сайта уже добавлены в базу phpBB3).
Интересует то как начать в phpBB3 сессию пользователя.
Вот мы к примеру имеем id пользователя из phpBB3 или весь набор полей из таблицы users. Что нужно сделать чтобы авторизовать его. Насколько я понял авторизация происходит в этом участке кода файла ucp.php:

```
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
...
case 'login':
        if ($user->data['is_registered'])
        {
            redirect(append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}index.$phpEx"));
        }

        login_box(request_var('redirect', "index.$phpEx"));
    break;
```

Но вот как авторизовать созданного вручную пользовоателя понять не могу

P.S. Разобрался кажется, после получения session_id необходимо записать столбец session_user_id таблицы sessions ID необходимого пользователя.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для авторизации без пароля в PhpBB 3 нужно воспользоваться следующей констркуцией.

```
global $user;
$user->session_create(ID пользователя, 0, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, такую конструкцию не нашёл нигде, поэтому написал создание сессии сам, но пожалуй заменю на более правильное решение)

Comment: Осталось только научится её использовать, так как в таблицу с сессиями почему то запись соответствующая не заносится(

Comment: Если быть точнее, то запись в таблицу sessions добавляется, но там юзер не тот которого я передаю методу

Comment: Я на только что установленом форуме протестировал вроде все работает и в sessions пишется тот юзер под которым залогинелся. Может быть у Вас какие то моды установлены которые портят метод?