# Как к phpbb-форуму прикрутить авторизацию по ip?

Tags: php, node.js, авторизация, phpbb

Идея авторизации следующая: если пользователь заходит из корпоративной сети, то берётся его ip-адрес, на основе которого определяется имя компьютера. По имени компьютера делается поиск в active directory, из результата берётся пользователь.

Как прикрутить эту схему к phpbb? Если зашедший пользователь ещё не существует, его надо сразу создать. Никаких лишних вопросов пользователю задаваться не должно. Другие способы авторизации пока не рассматриваются.

Вот соответствующий код определения пользователя на node.js:

```
const LdapAuth = require('ldapauth-fork');
const dns = require('dns');
const http = require('http');

function findUsers(wkstname, callback) {
  ldap = new LdapAuth({
    url: "LDAP://smth.city.example.com",
    bindDn: "CN=Auto User,OU=Auto Users,OU=Service,DC=city,DC=example,DC=com",
    bindCredentials: "JustAPassword",
    searchBase: "OU=UsersCity,DC=city,DC=example,DC=com",
    //searchFilter: "(mail={{username}})"
    searchFilter: "(WKSTName={{wkstname}})"
  });

  var searchFilter = `(WKSTName=${wkstname})`;

  var opts = {filter: searchFilter, scope: ldap.opts.searchScope};

  ldap._search(ldap.opts.searchBase, opts, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      ldap.close();
      return callback(err);
    }

    var users = result.map(u => ({login: u.cn, info: u.title}));
    ldap.close();
    return callback(null, users);
  });
};

function getUserByIp(ip, callback) {
  dns.reverse(ip, function(err, domains) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err, null);
    }

    if(domains.length) {
      findUsers(domains[0].match(/^\w+/)[0], (err, users) => {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err, null);
        }

        if (users.length !== 1) {
          return callback(users, null);
        }

        return callback(null, users[0]);
      });
    }

    return callback("No domains", null);
  });
}

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var ip = request.connection.remoteAddress;

  getUserByIp(ip, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello, " + (user ? user.login : "guest") + "!");
  });
});

server.listen(8081, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: Потенциально полезно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/283249/178988

Comment: если нет то просто создать с автоматическим логином (к примеру ip) и паролем рэндомном. И вывеску пож. укажите свои мыло, и как он укажет отослать инструкцию и логин с инструкцией выстановить пароль.